# moveable form without title

Tags: c#, forms, class

I was looking on this forum earlier to help with this issue i am having. Basically I am dynamically creating a form from a class which i want to be draggable around the screen without the title bars. The code i came across is :

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void window_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

However when i try to compile I get the following error:

> Error 1   The name 'Handle' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\practiceProgressBar2\practiceProgressBar2\Notifications.cs  109 29  practiceProgressBar2

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong as I have been tackling this all day

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using this code in a form, can you post more of the class? Does it inherit from `Form`?

Comment: public void startMessageIndicator(string message)
        {window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 150);
                window.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                window.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise;
                window.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise;

Comment: string message = Interaction.InputBox("Question?", "Title", "Default Text");
            messageindicator.startMessageIndicator(message);

Comment: I have shown some class code and also the main code which calls the class

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
```

To:

```
SendMessage(((Form)sender).Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
```

If you have other controls, like Labels, pointing to that same handler, then you could use this instead to make it drag when you also drag the Labels:

```
SendMessage(((Control)sender).FindForm().Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you and just replace the word Form with the name of the window that I want this feature on?

Comment: You can just leave it as the generic `Form` type, no need to cast to a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the form's `WndProc` method instead.

```
public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
public const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
public const int HTCLIENT = 1;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        if (m.Result.ToInt32() == HTCLIENT)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
    }
}
```